# Python Multithreading gets stuck at last task

Tags: python, multithreading

I run a multithreaded task in Python where I scrape URLs. Let's say I have 10k URLs to scrape, and I loop over slices of 100 URLs and have 50 threads work on those URLs:

```
def main(input_tuple):
    try:
        res = send_request(f"input_tuple[1]")
        if res == False:
            return
        some_data = logic_a(f"input_tuple[1]") # I parse HTML and write data to DB here
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("error in main: ", e)
        return
    logging.info("Thread ID: %s, Test Twentyfour", threading.get_ident())


if __name__=="__main__":
    my_urls = [...] # 10k URLs in here
    start, end = 1000, 1100
    increment = 100
    for _ in range(len(my_urls) // increment):
        my_list_slice = my_urls[start:end]

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
            results = executor.map(main, my_list_slice)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
        start += increment
        end += increment
```

Now, the function iterates over a couple of slices of 100 URLs, and after a few iterations, the last thread of the current iteration just stops after executing main() (i.e. I find "Thread ID: 123456, Test Twentyfour" in my logs). However, it doesn't print the results in:

```
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Any idea why that might be? I tried pretty much everything I found on SO regarding this already, and don't get anywhere.

Comment: It's probably "stuck" in either *send_request()* or *logic_a()*

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case, as the last thing I find in my logs is "Thread ID: 123456, Test Twentyfour". So it does end with the main()

Comment: Are you aware that your loop is (almost certainly) wrong. If your list of URLs has 10,000 elements then your range will be 100 (i.e., 10,000 / 100). *start* and *end* never change. Therefore you will process the same 100 URLs (my_urls[start:end]) 100 times. You can't be certain if your threads have all terminated normally because you could return without any logging. Add some logging for the case when *res == False* then count the number of log lines.

Comment: I forgot to add those lines of code in the post here, but I do increment start and end after every iteration of the for loop. I updated the code above to match what I run.

Good point with logging when res == False. I'll do that and count the log lines.

Comment: Why do you skip the first 1,000 URLs?

Comment: This was just an example. However, in reality, I do skip the first few thousand URLs because I already scraped them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254638/discussion-between-darkknight-and-tom).